# How to move the text with range

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a range like you see in the picture below:

[image]

Here is my code for this:

```html
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="distance" class="form-label">Aranılan lokasyona uzaklık</label>
       <div class="distance">
           <output>40 </output>
           <span>km uzaklık</span>
       </div>
       <input type="range" value="40" min="1" max="50" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" class="form-range" id="distance">
       <div class="total-distance">50</div>
     </div>
```

So what I am trying to achieve, I want to move this  with the range input.

PS: I am using bootstrap for range.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "move"? Like, add padding to the left/top? Or is that a phrasing issue and you actually want to display the range's value in the text?

Comment: I want 40 km uzaklık move to left or right with the range and 40 should also change because of the range rate

Comment: So change position or change value?

Comment: Both needs to be changed actually

Comment: How far did you get when you attempted to solve this problem? Can you share your JavaScript as well as the HTML? What went wrong - and in what way - with your attempts?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/) to maybe get an idea for more dynamically looking solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution I developed below is used, it is necessary to develop a transform function to evaluate the new position of the text. The following equation generates the `margin` value for the new position according to the change amount. For example;

```
T(x) = x * 4 + 60;
```

If there isn't an easier method, the transform function should also take the page width as input:

```
T(x, width)
```

```js
let output = document.getElementById('result');
let distance = document.getElementById('distance');

function changeValue(value){
  output.innerHTML = `${50 - parseInt(value)}`;
  
  /* If this method is used, it is necessary to develop a transformation method. */ 
  let result = parseInt(value) * 4 + 60;
  
  distance.style.marginLeft = `${result}px`;
}

changeValue(40);
```

```css
input{
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#distance{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="distance" class="form-label">Aranılan lokasyona uzaklık</label>
    <div id="distance">
        <output id="result">40</output>
        <span> km uzaklık</span>
    </div>
    
    <input onchange="changeValue(this.value)" type="range" value="40" min="0" max="50" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" class="form-range" id="distance">
  
    <div class="total-distance">Total: 50</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good old native JS... what a breeze!

First, check out the code snippet below

Now - let's break the solution down

**CSS** - The styling properties allow the ,moving label to have its own width + able it to move around (as required)

**JS** - Register an event (I've used the `mouse up` event but you can use `on change` event or any other to suit your requirements). Then, make a simple calculation - how much progress have we done, project it to the actual `input` size. The only thing left is to adjust the new position to your label

Hope this help you to get things started

ENJOY

```js
function x(input) {
    const percent = input.value / 50
  const position = percent * input.clientWidth
  const labelElement = document.querySelector('.distance')
  labelElement.style.left = `${position - labelElement.clientWidth / 2}px`
}
```

```css
.distance {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="distance" class="form-label">Aranılan lokasyona uzaklık</label>
  <br/>
  <div class="distance">
    <output>40 </output>
    <span>km uzaklık</span>
  </div>
  <input onMouseUp=x(this) type="range" value="40" min="1" max="50" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" class="form-range" id="distance">
  <div class="total-distance">50</div>
</div>
```